# Probability of sum of dice is composite

Tags: probability, prime-numbers, dice

Let n dice be rolled. Let $S_{i}$ be the sum of the first $i$ rolls for $i=1...n$

Find $Prob($All $S_{i}$ are composite) as $n$ tends to ∞

My guess is 0 but how can I prove this? Or if I'm wrong how do I proceed?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you please explain what you mean by *composite*? You are also saying that "$n$ dice" are rolled. Do you mean that a die is rolled $n$ times ($i=1,\ldots,n$)? Although your problem statement is not very clear to me, you might be looking for [Kolmogorov's 0-1 law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law)

Comment: Thanks. Some clarifications: Composite as in not prime. There is no difference between rolling 1 dice n times and taking the sum and rolling n dice and taking their sum

Comment: This is just intuition talking but why not try and find the probability $P_0=P(x\in\mathbb P>0)$ such that $x \in S_i$, and $\mathbb P$ is the set of prime numbers. So then you just need to compute $1-P_0$ .

Answer (score 1):

Consider the first $n$ rolls for **sufficiently large** $n$. Let $$\mathbb{P} = \{0\}\cup\{ 1\leq i \leq n-1\mid \text{there is at least one prime in the range }[S_{i} + 1, S_{i} + 6]\}$$
Since there are more than $\frac{n}{\ln n}$ primes in the range $[1, n]$ for $n \geq 17$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities)), the size of $\mathbb{P}$ is more than $\frac{n}{6\ln n}$. Hence, 
\begin{align}
\Pr(S_1, S_2, \cdots, S_n \text{ are all composite})~\leq~\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n / (6\ln n)}
\end{align}
When $n$ goes to $\infty$, the probability goes to $0$.